# After the Apple developer attack: How to recover missing App IDs / Certificates / Provisioning profiles?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, iphone-developer-program

Has anyone noticed that certain files are missing ***in the Apple developer portal*** after the recent attacks? Suddenly I am missing a certificate as well as a couple provisioning profiles. My current machine has the files but since I want to add devices I need to add them to the provisioning profile - the one that's missing!

I would really like to avoid having to create new credentials for my app. Has anyone experienced this and found a solution?

Comment: I had similar issues. Unfortunately, the only way I was able to get everything going again was to start from scratch with new certificates and profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't say I've seen that happen on any of my accounts, however if you do have things missing give Apple Developer Support a call and see if they have any lingering issues as a result of the rebuild.

I'd speculate, however, the quickest way to getting back up and running will be to just recreate the certificates and provisioning profiles.  Since you have everything locally, then all you really need to do is open the .mobileprovision file in your favorite text editor then remake the profile using those same settings.  So long as you use the same AppID as before, nearly everything will automatically wire up correctly after downloading and installing the updated certificate provisioning profile on your machine.

While I normally recommend cleaning up old certificates and profiles anytime you download new ones, in this case it would seem prudent to keep the old stuff around until you are certain you've gotten things migrated over to the new profile. Provisioning can be a tricking thing, so if you have questions, edit your question or add another comment!